# I have written a Cobol Report Writer program, but I cannot compile it

Tags: cobol

I wrote this after I read that Cobol supports Report Writer, only to discover afterwards the version of z/OS we have here at school doesn't actually support it.

I'm wondering if there is a way for this to easily be converted to basic Cobol or if there is any kind of compiler i might find and use.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Without seeing the `report section` it would be difficult to agree with "easily". You should look at GnuCOBOL for a free compiler with support for report writer.

Comment: Thanks Rick! I was just downloading that... I feel like i'm gonna have to rewrite this damn thing and I'm kicking myself for learning something new and giving Report Writer a shot...

Comment: @RedScofield why would you kick yourself for attempting to learn a new skill? Yes you may need to rewrite, but that's not a bad thing

Answer (score 1):

Having seen the `REPORT SECTION`; yes, it may be easily converted.

For the conversion, a choice needs to be made between using IBM `POSITIONING` or standard COBOL `ADVANCING` in the `WRITE` statement; and `END-OF-PAGE` exception or writing your own code for moving to the next page.

I adjusted some spacing and made a few corrections to the original. I generated 120 records for test data, all random numbers.

```
   REPORT SECTION.
   RD  PRODUCT-REPORT 
       PAGE LIMIT 59
       HEADING 1
       FIRST DETAIL 6
       LAST DETAIL 59.

   01  HEAD1 TYPE PH. 
     03  LINE 1.
       05  COLUMN 1  PIC X(5) VALUE 'DATE:'.
       05  COLUMN 8  PIC 9(2) SOURCE WS-CD-MONTH.
       05  COLUMN 10 PIC X VALUE '/'.
       05  COLUMN 11 PIC 9(2) SOURCE WS-CD-DAY.
       05  COLUMN 13 PIC X VALUE '/'.
       05  COLUMN 14 PIC 9(2) SOURCE WS-CD-YEAR.
       05  COLUMN 33 PIC X(19) VALUE 'MASTER PRODUCT LIST'.
       05  COLUMN 72 PIC X(5) VALUE 'PAGE:'.
       05  COLUMN 77  PIC ZZ9 SOURCE PAGE-COUNTER.

     03  LINE 2.
       05  COLUMN 1  PIC X(5) VALUE 'TIME:'.
       05  COLUMN 9  PIC 9(2) SOURCE WS-CD-HOURS.
       05  COLUMN 11 PIC X VALUE ':'.
       05  COLUMN 12 PIC 9(2) SOURCE WS-CD-MINUTES.
       05  COLUMN 72 PIC X(8) VALUE 'PRODLIST'.

     03  LINE 4.
       05  COLUMN 1  PIC X(5) VALUE 'CODE:'.
       05  COLUMN 8  PIC X(5) VALUE 'TYPE:'.
       05  COLUMN 18 PIC X(12) VALUE 'DESCRIPTION:'.
       05  COLUMN 66 PIC X(6) VALUE 'PRICE:'.

     03  LINE 5.
       05 COLUMN 1 PIC X(80) VALUE ALL '='.

   01  PRODLINE TYPE DE. 
     03 LINE PLUS 1.
       05 COLUMN 1  PIC X(5) SOURCE PRODCODE.
       05 COLUMN 8  PIC X(8) SOURCE PRODTYPE.
       05 COLUMN 18 PIC X(32) SOURCE PRODDESC.
       05 COLUMN 66 PIC $ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZ9 SOURCE PRODCOST.
```

Ran the program and got this partial output.

```
DATE:  11/08/18                 MASTER PRODUCT LIST                    PAGE:  1 
TIME:   15:54                                                          PRODLIST 

CODE:  TYPE:     DESCRIPTION:                                    PRICE:         
================================================================================
47638  54784935  48116892                                        $  1,461,160   
26450  06251370  81421270                                        $  7,765,877
```

Comment: The original code was at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.cobol/wPYffAgS2NI/Ha2w1m8GBAAJ

Answer (score 0):

The IBM COBOL family does provide Report Writer. All you need is a compiler "plug-in". Look for product 5798-DYR COBOL Report writer Precompiler. It works seamlessly. No need to convert any code. Ask for free on-line user manual.